# NoClassDefFoundError on class present in jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

I searched a lot, but could not find a solution for my issue. I generated stubs from a wsdl using wsimport, and added to my project. Following is the error I get when I try to initialize a class MyServiceEp from the stub. I identify this as **probably a j-boss 7 issue**. But I am new to the server and do not know the workaround for this. I tried adding

```
            <property name="org.jboss.osgi.system.modules.extra">
                javax.xml.ws
            </property>
```

to my standalone.xml as I read in another forum that this is the workaround for this, but could not get the issue solved..

```
10:49:23,351 ERROR [org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory
.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/abc/bcd/MyServiceEp
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:288) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans
-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-
3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at 
].................................
..............................
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/abc/bcd/MyServiceEp
            at org.xx.portal.ws.client.MyServiceImpl.setMyClient(MyServiceImpl.java:37) [classes:]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
            at 


      ... 53 more
```

I am using **Liferay 6.2** - **jboss 7.1.1 final** bundled version and use **spring MVC**. The NoClassDefFound error occurs for an auto generated class in the stub. I will post more details if required.

**Update**

I run the server with verbose:class and got the following error as well..

```
12:31:00,501 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class gov.or.hix.wsdl.ee.individualcaseservice.IndividualCaseServiceEp in Modul
e "deployment.My-Portlet-1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/abc/bcd/MyServiceEp (Module "deployment.My-Portlet-1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at 
..................................
................................
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54) [portal-service.jar:]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116) [portal-service.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Service from [Module "deployment.My-Portlet-1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        ... 75 more
```

Comment: why are you using org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet?

Comment: Because mine is a portlet application in liferay. It is auto generated when portlet is created. That shouldnot be the issue. I have used it before.

Comment: For anyone reading this like me later: Make sure, you are running the .jar with same JRE / JDK version as was compiled.
Ideally, I recommend you to run with identical JDK, not even same version JRE. This would help me. HTH...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this solved. It was an issue due to jboss 7. Jboss 7 doesnot have the files for javax.xml.ws.Service and hence the error. I got this resolved by adding the following dependencies to my project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Adding this resolved the  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service error and hence the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using **Eclipse IDE**. Upon this assumption, try the following steps:

1. You've got your stubs regarding your web service say in the directory *webservices*. Now Link the source of these file in your project.

**Right click you project** > **Properties** > **Java Build Path** > **Locate Source Tab**  > **Click Link Source** > **Locate *webservices*'s path from the directory structure**

2. Click **OK** and **OK** again.
3. Now try to import the classes regarding your studs.

*This will definitely work for you as it worked in my case.*

Comment: I use maven dependency to link the project

Comment: Just try above steps along with your other configuration in you build path.

Comment: Hope you didn't notice the second log I posted. That said the NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service. This comes usually in server bundle itself, but for jboss7 only, we have to add it explicitly. Got it resolved. Find my answer